# RSA encryption back from server nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, rsa

I am developing one mobile application using which i have to connect to my server via REST services.

I want to encrypt data transition from client to server and vice versa.
for that i gone through so many documents for RSA but everywhere it is saying that using public key in client side we can encrypt and using private key we can decrypt.

But the problem is after login i want to send "user details" from server as response in encrypted way.

so question here is can we encrypt using private key and decrypt using public key?
if yes then please suggest me some library for client side and as well as for nodejs server side.

if no. then tell me the solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use HTTPS. It does public/private key encryption transparently.

Comment: so does it encrypts from server side as a response?

Comment: Yes. It does. The entire communication is encrypted.

Comment: because i monitored using some software about the data coming and going from my server...so i found that after HTTPS client data is getting encrypted but server response is raw data

Comment: @Rahul — That sounds like a flaw in the method you used to monitor it.

Comment: okay so i will test using some good software then, by the way self signed certificate with 2048 bit is enough for security? or do i need some other mechanism